# Android Studio - Gradle sync error on gradle-diagnostics-X.X.X.jar

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just updated Android Studio and I can't sync my project anymore.

The event log reports:

```
Gradle sync failed: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-X.X.X/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-X.X.X.jar (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

To solve the Gradle sync error, open **`gradle-wrapper.properties`** file and update the Gradle wrapper distribution version from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-X.X.X-all.zip
```

To:

- Android Studio 3.4
  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`
- Android Studio 2.3 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip`
- Android Studio 2.2 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`
- Android Studio 2.1 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip`
- Android Studio 2.0 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
- Android Studio 1.5 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip`
- Android Studio 1.3 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip`

You can find the latest Gradle wrapper version visiting:
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

**EDIT**:
As a side note, as @SeBsZ suggests,
the official repository of the Android Gradle plugin switched from MavenCentral to jCenter ([see Bintray blog post](http://blog.bintray.com/2015/02/09/android-studio-migration-from-maven-central-to-jcenter/)).

Make sure your project **`build.gradle`** file contains the new repository and the new classpath:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is not strictly related to the question problem, but since we are already migrating to the new IDE preview it's better to make sure everything is in place.

Comment: That did not work for me.
What distro are you using?

Comment: @КодСерфинг145 I'm on Mac OS X, have you tried to Build>Clean and then resync your project?
Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: For me moving Android-studio to /opt/android-studio worked but this is probably only working on linux.

I'm using Play Linux (Insider build)

Comment: @КодСерфинг145 yes, installing Android Studio on /opt/android-studio is the best practice on Linux.
Please see the updated answer to configure the correct Gradle wrapper and Android Gradle Plugin versions.
Have a nice day!

Comment: **Note for troubleshooting**: *gradle-wrapper.properties* is not visible if you are viewing as *Project*. It is easy to find under *Gradle Scripts* if you switch to the *Android* view.

Comment: I had to do the opposite: Change from gradle-2.4-all.zip to gradle-2.2.1-all.zip...

Comment: thank you. just updated and. studio to 1.5 and updated gradle.properties to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-all.zip and it worked nicely (NOV 2015)

Comment: FYI - For Studio 1.5, had to use Gradle 2.8, not 2.9.  So distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip instead of distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-all.zip.   In case 2.9 doesn't work for you...

Comment: This happened when I upgraded the Android Studio and the Parse Starter project stopped working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ps: Android Studio 2.3 use  gradle-3.3-all.zip

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you are using an older project then you might still be using the maven repository. Make sure you change the repositories in your top-level build.gradle from maven() to jcenter(). Then make sure you are using the correct dependency as well: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'` for the new 1.3 preview.

Comment: I think this solution is a bit out of topic (the question is specific to the erroneous Gradle plugin version). Maybe you should post another question for the Maven-related problem you experienced! Anyway, thank you for your contribution: I'll check the classpath thing as soon as I'm back in office!

Answer (score 1):

For me helped to set chmod on the .gradle directory to 777. After this whole Android studio started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue after updating android studio to 3.4

I resolve this updatig gradle-wrapper.properties

I had

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

I leave

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

and with this To solve the Gradle sync error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the weirdest thing ever and I never expected it to work but this:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

worked and got everything fixed (it was the '\' after https). It does make sense since that is an actual link to a file.

Answer (score 0):

check your .bash_profile file and make sure your GRADLE_HOME points to a valid path, if things were working and you face this issue after android studio update, chances are your gradle got updated too.
Here is the example of my gradle home in .bash_profile:
export GRADLE_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/bin

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a newly set up Android Studio 2.2.2, gradle wrapper 2.14.1. I loaded the project before i installed the needed android-23 library and installed java after Android Studio installation.

Error message in Android Studio 2.2.2:

```
Error:The specified Gradle distribution
'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip' does 
not appear to contain a Gradle distribution.
```

Error message in cmd:

```
projectfolder> gradlew
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:34) 
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

When i used gradle from cmd however it worked

```
projectfolder> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\AndroidStudio2.0\gradle\gradle-2.14.1\bin\
projectfolder> set GRADLE_HOME=C:\AndroidStudio2.0\gradle\gradle-2.14.1\bin\
projectfolder> cd C:\projectfolder\
projectfolder> gradle
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

In cmd i see that the gradle versions and android sdk version were correct

```
C:\>set | find "JAVA_HOME"
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\
```

However in C:\Users\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\log\idea.log it said something else:

```
2016-11-29 16:04:10,597 [ 107684]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/AndroidStudio2.0/jre 
2016-11-29 16:04:10,597 [ 107684]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/AndroidStudio2.0/jre
```

After messing up Android Studio config files i ended up reinstalling everything in correct order (Java, Android Studio, Project) and it worked.

Answer (score -3):

I got the same issue after updating my android studio to 1.5

Here is my error stack trace.

Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Kargo'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/adiyatmubarak/Documents/android-studio/gradle/**gradle-2.4**/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-2.4.jar (No such file or directory)

After I checked to the android studio instalation directory within gradle, my gradle was **gradle-2.8** I don't know how to setup my android studio path location, but for temporary fix I just rename it to **gradle-2.4** and my problem solved.