# /tools/external/gradle/gradle-4.5-bin.zip (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a project. My code was working fine. After I merged, I am getting this error when I try to clean/build. Any ideas what steps I should follow to fix it?

```
/tools/external/gradle/gradle-4.5-bin.zip (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on something of AOSP,

1. Check that /tools/external/gradle/gradle-X.X-bin.zip is existed?
2. Open file `<project_source>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
3. Change property `distributionUrl` accordingly

Otherwise, refer [Android Studio - Gradle sync error on gradle-diagnostics-X.X.X.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526613/android-studio-gradle-sync-error-on-gradle-diagnostics-x-x-x-jar/30526660) to update your `gradle-wrapper.properties`