# What gradle file can I use to resolve this error?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I am trying to compile an android application, and I get the following error:
The specified Gradle installation directory '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.8' does not exist.
Do you know where can I find the related dependencies in order to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Gradle sync error on gradle-diagnostics-X.X.X.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526613/android-studio-gradle-sync-error-on-gradle-diagnostics-x-x-x-jar)