# Android Studio Bumblebee: Gradle sync failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-bumblebee

After upgrading to Bumblebee, some of my projects now show this:

```
The specified Gradle installation directory '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1' does not exist.
```

How can I solved this issue? I have tried some old solutions (eg [Android Studio - Gradle sync error on gradle-diagnostics-X.X.X.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526613/android-studio-gradle-sync-error-on-gradle-diagnostics-x-x-x-jar)) and does not seem to work. Also tried clear cache and restart.

Answer (score 29):

Go to Android Studio Preferences → Build, Execute, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle.

Change the "Use Gradle from:" option from "Specified location" to your properties file.

[image]
<sub>(Screenshot provided by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14455214/mike))</sub>

Then, click "Try Again".

Comment: after set this property, i can not apple the change. Any one else has the problem like me?